# Tomcat 8 - Enable RewriteValve without chaning server.xml

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat8

I am running an application inside a tomcat whos configuration i am not allowed to change. Therefore my database connection for example is configured in

```
tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/context.xml.default
```

Now i need to make use of the **RewriteValve**.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

=> Is it possible to enable it without touching `tomcat/conf/context.xml` and `tomcat/conf/server.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the configuration in `/META-INF/context.xml` of the built WAR file. I imagine this has limitations, since you probably don't one app changing URLs over other apps.

Source: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-context